# qemu stuck on booting from rom

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, qemu

Compiling linux from source and it's stick on "Booting from Rom"

My menuconfig is the standard configuration.

```
qemu-system-x86_64  -kernel vmlinux -initrd initrd.img
```

[image]